# How to update PostgreSQL full text search field when relational data changes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have the following strategy for the full text search in my web app which uses PostgreSQL for relational data storage. For example I will take `Invoices` table.

1. In the tables I have one additional field `ALTER TABLE invoices ADD COLUMN tsv tsvector` on which the full text search query is done like this `... WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('query:*') ...`
2. On every full text search table I have set an update trigger that updates `tsv` field on every change of the record. Update sets and concatenates the data from different fields to `tsv` field, sets the right weights, etc...
3. The data that gets set into `tsv` field can also be relational data from other tables. From example in table `invoices` I have `client_id` field but since I want to search invoices by the client name as well I also include `clients.client_name` data in the `invoices.tsv` field

My question is what is the best strategy to keep the relational data in tsv selectors in sync. In above scenario -> if client name changes I would need to update this in `tsv` field for every invoice...

Should I set cron job setup up that would do this every night? It could be also done with triggers, but since my database schema is very large I am scared it might get out of control if I have triggers all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the clients name into the tsv field you will end up with more complexity. You might want to look into Materialized views as mentioned in [this article](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/). The trade-off might be speed in showing results and the need to refresh the view periodically. As of Postgres 9.4 you can now refresh a view concurrently.

Another thing you could do is create an update trigger in the Client table and when there's an update it will update the data in the Invoices table as well.